# Returning HTTRANSPARENT for WM_NCHITTEST in a plugin

Tags: c, winapi, plugins, hook

How can I get a plugin to make the program have my clicks go though the window? I heard I would have to return HTTRANSPARENT for WM_NCHITTEST. Is it possible to do that with hooking? This is as far as I have got in my hook:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK myHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    CWPSTRUCT* pwp = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
    if (pwp->message==WM_NCHITTEST)
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("NCHITTEST has been receieved."), TEXT("NCHITTEST"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);                
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return HTTRANSPARENT for WM_NCHITTEST in a hook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357028/how-do-i-return-httransparent-for-wm-nchittest-in-a-hook)

Comment: I **apologize** for that, I'm very close to finishing the plugin and this is the last thing I need to solve. I wanted to get this on front page of newest but I guess it didn't matter in the end. I'm not great with WinAPI since I'm still learning it, but I wanted to get this plugin working for a program I am using.